# Как вывести количество записей даже если база данных пустая?

Tags: java, android, sqlite

Работаю с sqlite. В настройках приложения есть возможность добавлять группы, в которые потом можно добавлять каналы. В таблице `channels` есть поле типа `TEXT` и равно оно id групп разделенных запятой. Например, `groups = 1,2,3,4,5,6`. В настройках группы выводится как Имя и количество каналов в группе.

```
SELECT g.*,COUNT(c._id) as _count FROM groups g,playlists p LEFT JOIN channels c ON p._active = 1 AND c._groups LIKE '%' || g._id || ',%' GROUP BY g._id ORDER BY g._name
```

Работает все хорошо, но только если в таблице `channels` нет ни одной записи, то ни одной группы в настройках не выводится. Помогите исправить sql запрос таким образом что бы если таблица `channels` была пустая, то группы выводились и количество каналов в них было ноль.

1. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS groups (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,name TEXT)`
2. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS playlists (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,name TEXT,active INTEGER,count INTEGER)`
3. `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS channels (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL,name TEXT,groups TEXT,playlist_id INTEGER)`
4. groups - 1,Фильмы
5. groups - 2,Сериалы
6. groups - 3,Новости
7. playlists - 4,Мой лист,1,200
8. channels - 1,1 канал,'1,3'
9. channels - 2,Россия,''
10. channels - 3,ТНТ,'1,3'

Comment: Приведите структуру и связи таблиц, и почему вы джойните к плейлистам?

Comment: Связей нету.Я думаю они просто не к чему.groups = id,name,count. playlists = id,name,active.channels = id,name,desc,groups,playlist_id.Точно нужно джойнить к каналам,но все равно если нет плейлиста то каналов и не будет.И опять ничего не выведется.

Comment: Инструкции `create table` к посту приложите и хотя бы одну запись в каждой таблице. Так всем будет проще.

Comment: К каким каналам? Вы сейчас джойните плейлисты с каналами а будете джойнить каналы с каналами? Вы три дня назад задавали тот же вопрос. И до сих пор не удосужились прочесть мат часть?

Comment: 3 дня назад был другой вопрос.Я сейчас джойню группы с каналами.

Comment: Как вы думаете что у вас будет если в группах будует 11, а вы захотите выбрать группы с ид 1?  Сделайте нормально связи, тогда таких проблем станет меньше.

Comment: @Ivan Весьма странные связи, ну да ладно. Смоделировал вашу БД, попробовал ваш запрос исправив имена полей, `_name` -> `name` и т.д. Выполнил имея записи в channels, а после удалив их от туда. Запрос выполнился, в _count отобразилось 0. Вы уверены, что у вас проблема не с таблицей playlists? Может быть в вашем случае она была тоже пуста? Вы же соединяете channels с playlists,а уже после декартовым произведением playlists с groups.

Comment: @GreyGoblin  playlists то же пуста в моей проблеме.Просто например в настройках группы есть группы, но плейлиста еще нет то должно выводиться имя группы и количество т.е. 0.

Comment: @Ivan ну что же вы тогда людей дезинформируете? Жалуетесь же на таблицу channels. Переделайте декартово соединение playlists с groups не левое groups с playlists и все станет хорошо.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT g.*,COUNT(c._id) as _count 
FROM groups g 
LEFT JOIN playlists p 
    LEFT JOIN channels c 
    ON p._active = 1 AND c._groups LIKE '%' || g._id || ',%' 
ON 1 
GROUP BY g._id
ORDER  BY g._name
```

Comment: Спасибо большое очень выручили.А то еще пол проекта делать, а андроид студия после обновлений windows раз через 10 компилирует проект.А я сижу и делаю так SELECT g.*,COUNT(c._id) as _count FROM playlists p,groups g LEFT JOIN channels c ON p._active = 1 AND c._groups LIKE '%' || g._id || ',%' GROUP BY g._id ORDER BY g._name

Comment: @Ivan вам просто нужно делить задачи на простые. Вот например вам же нужны все поля из групп? Пишите простой запрос, который вернет вам все эти поля. Далее соединяете со второй таблицей. Проверяете чтобы ничего не сломалось, в том числе на граничных случаях, то есть  когда в правой или левой таблице пусто. Далее третью таблицу, пока без условий. Проверяете. Потом первое условие. Проверяете и т.д. Иначе можно сделать ошибку в самом начале, а искать будете в конце.

Comment: так вроде делю и делаю.Чисто в андроид студии изменил запрос и ждать пака с компилируется на удачу.Сейчас буду искать sqlite редактор да бы быстрее пошло дело.

Comment: @Ivan в нете можно найти онлайн тестеры запросов, где можно насоздавать своих табличек и потестить запросы. Например вот: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_delete

Comment: ok  spasibo bydy znat

Comment: Вы не знаете есть ли возможность в ListView напрямую добавить 0 позицию свою или может в курсор?Нужно 0 позицией сделать возврат назад.Нажимаю на группу где есть каналы и в этом же ListView вывожу новый список из каналов в группе.Соответственно в onClickItem группы добавляю заголовок addHeaderView с кнопкой назад.Но нажатию на кнопку назад удаляю ее.Все хорошо но в андроид до версии 4.4 нужно сначала установить адаптер, а потом добавить заголовок.Я получаю курсор в cursorLoader.Соответственно сначала добавляю заголовок, а потом устанавливаю adapter и приложение вылетает.