# Как получить количество строк в sqlite в java android studio?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite, android-sdk

Есть база данных sqlite, как получить количество содержащихся в ней строк?

Comment: Достать список строк и узнать длину этого списка. На каком этапе у Вас возникла проблема?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вывести количество записей даже если база данных пустая?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/589230/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%b5%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b5-%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b1%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d1%85-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d1%8f)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С помощью [DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/DatabaseUtils.html#queryNumEntries(android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)).